# MySql query string to sql object

Tags: zend-framework2

Using Zend Framework 2 is possible to get a sql string from a tablegateway object, like this:

```
public function test(){
   $sql = $this->tableGateway->getSql();
   $select = $sql->select();
   $select->where(array('title' => 'abracadabra'));
   $select->where
     ->NEST->
           equalTo('id', 1)
               ->OR->
           equalTo('artist', 'Tony')
     ->UNNEST;

   $select->limit(1);

   return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
}

//code ignored here//

echo $sql->getSqlstringForSqlObject($select);
```

I was wondering if it could be possible to do the opposite, and basically set a query string and then get back a tableGateway object, the reason for this is that sometimes is needed to set a where clause dynamically, without having to know where to place/append it, example:

On a single query:

```
$sql = "select * from tbl_test";

if($isDynamic)
    $sql .= ' where test_id=1';
```

But on more complex query:

```
$sql = "select * from tbl_test inner join (select * from tbl_test 1) x on 1=1 where test_id is not null group by test_id";

//OF COURSE IT WILL FAIL.
if($isDynamic)
    $sql .= ' where test_id=1';
```

Using zf2 I could potentially do something like

- Setting the query string to a sql object.
- Then simply do $obj->where(array('test_id'=>1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I overloaded method *Zend\Db\Sql\Select*.

For your example of a complex query, I proceed as follows:

```
Your query : select * from tbl_test inner join (select * from tbl_test 1) x on 1=1 where test_id is not null group by test_id
My query : SELECT * FROM (select * from tbl_test inner join (select * from tbl_test 1) x on 1=1 where test_id is not null group by test_id) tmp WHERE test_id=1;
```

If your complex query use alias *tmp* then change in the method *renderTable()*.
Here is how my class is used (change the namespace as need):

```
use SbmPdf\Model\Db\Sql\Select;
$sql = "select * from tbl_test inner join (select * from tbl_test 1) x on 1=1 where test_id is not null group by test_id";
$select = new Select($sql);
$select->where(array('id' => 1));
```

Here is my class (change the namespace as need):

```
/**
 * Surcharge de la classe Zend\Db\Sql\Select pour exécuter une requête complexe basée sur une chaine SQL
 *
 * On a ajouté la méthode setRecordSource qui permet de passer une chaine SQL complète comme source de donnée.
 * 
 * Lorsque la chaine SQL recordSource est donnée (constructeur ou setter), elle remplace la table indiquée dans FROM. 
 * En définitive, la méthode from() sera ignorée si la méthode recordSource() est appelée.
 * Par contre, si on n'appelle pas cette nouvelle méthode, la classe aura un comportement normal (à condition de ne
 * rien passer au constructeur).
 * 
 * Ensuite, pour exécuter la requête, il faut pratiquer de la façon suivante :
 *   $sqlString = $select->getSqlString($dbAdapter->getPlatform());
 *   $rowset = $dbAdapter->query($sqlString, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
 * 
 * @project sbm
 * @package SbmPdf/Model/Db/Sql
 * @filesource Select.php
 * @encodage UTF-8
 * @author DAFAP Informatique - Alain Pomirol (dafap@free.fr)
 * @date 19 août 2015
 * @version 2015-1
 */
namespace SbmPdf\Model\Db\Sql;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\ParameterContainer;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select as ZendSelect;

class Select extends ZendSelect
{

  private $recordSource;

  /**
   * On passe le recordSource (sql string) par le constructeur. On ne peut plus passer la table.
   *
   * @param string $recordSource            
   */
  public function __construct($recordSource = null)
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->recordSource = $recordSource;
  }

  /**
   * On peut aussi le passer par le setter
   *
   * @param string $recordSource            
   * @return \SbmPdf\Model\Db\Sql\Select
   */
  public function setRecordSource($recordSource)
  {
    $this->recordSource = $recordSource;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Surcharge de la méthode
   *
   * (non-PHPdoc)
   * 
   * @see \Zend\Db\Sql\Select::processSelect()
   */
  protected function processSelect(PlatformInterface $platform, DriverInterface $driver = null, ParameterContainer $parameterContainer = null)
  {
    $expr = 1;
    if (empty($this->recordSource)) {
        list ($table, $fromTable) = parent::resolveTable($this->table, $platform, $driver, $parameterContainer);
    } else {
        list ($table, $fromTable) = $this->resolveTable($this->recordSource, $platform);
    }
    // process table columns
    $columns = array();
    foreach ($this->columns as $columnIndexOrAs => $column) {
        if ($column === self::SQL_STAR) {
            $columns[] = array(
                $fromTable . self::SQL_STAR
            );
            continue;
        }

        $columnName = $this->resolveColumnValue(array(
            'column' => $column,
            'fromTable' => $fromTable,
            'isIdentifier' => true
        ), $platform, $driver, $parameterContainer, (is_string($columnIndexOrAs) ? $columnIndexOrAs : 'column'));
        // process As portion
        if (is_string($columnIndexOrAs)) {
            $columnAs = $platform->quoteIdentifier($columnIndexOrAs);
        } elseif (stripos($columnName, ' as ') === false) {
            $columnAs = (is_string($column)) ? $platform->quoteIdentifier($column) : 'Expression' . $expr ++;
        }
        $columns[] = (isset($columnAs)) ? array(
            $columnName,
            $columnAs
        ) : array(
            $columnName
        );
      }

      // process join columns
      foreach ($this->joins as $join) {
        $joinName = (is_array($join['name'])) ? key($join['name']) : $join['name'];
        $joinName = parent::resolveTable($joinName, $platform, $driver, $parameterContainer);

        foreach ($join['columns'] as $jKey => $jColumn) {
            $jColumns = array();
            $jFromTable = is_scalar($jColumn) ? $joinName . $platform->getIdentifierSeparator() : '';
            $jColumns[] = $this->resolveColumnValue(array(
                'column' => $jColumn,
                'fromTable' => $jFromTable,
                'isIdentifier' => true
            ), $platform, $driver, $parameterContainer, (is_string($jKey) ? $jKey : 'column'));
            if (is_string($jKey)) {
                $jColumns[] = $platform->quoteIdentifier($jKey);
            } elseif ($jColumn !== self::SQL_STAR) {
                $jColumns[] = $platform->quoteIdentifier($jColumn);
            }
            $columns[] = $jColumns;
        }
    }

    if ($this->quantifier) {
        $quantifier = ($this->quantifier instanceof ExpressionInterface) ? $this->processExpression($this->quantifier, $platform, $driver, $parameterContainer, 'quantifier') : $this->quantifier;
    }

    if (! isset($table)) {
        return array(
            $columns
        );
    } elseif (isset($quantifier)) {
        return array(
            $quantifier,
            $columns,
            $table
        );
    } else {
        return array(
            $columns,
            $table
        );
    }
  }

  protected function resolveTable($table, PlatformInterface $platform, DriverInterface $driver = null, ParameterContainer $parameterContainer = null)
  {
    $alias = null;

    if (is_array($table)) {
        $alias = key($table);
        $table = current($table);
    } else {
        $alias = 'tmp';
    }
    $fromTable = $platform->quoteIdentifier($alias);
    $table = $this->renderTable($table, $fromTable, false);
    if ($alias) {} else {
        $fromTable = $table;
    }

    if ($this->prefixColumnsWithTable && $fromTable) {
        $fromTable .= $platform->getIdentifierSeparator();
    } else {
        $fromTable = '';
    }

    return array(
        $table,
        $fromTable
    );
  }

  protected function renderTable($table, $alias = null, $parent = true)
  {
    if ($parent) {
        return parent::renderTable($table, $alias);
    } else {
        if (empty($alias)) {
            $alias = 'tmp';
        }
        return "($table) AS $alias";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alain, that is what I was looking for, just wondering if it will be able to parse any kind of select query or just this specific case?

Comment: I use it for many applications to create customized PDF documents. But to say it parse any kind of select query ... one must be careful and try !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly `where` clause with your cording.

```
public function test(){ 
$sql = $this->tableGateway->getSql();
$select = $sql->select();
$select->where(array('title' => 'abracadabra'));
$select->where
 ->NEST->
       equalTo('id', 1)
           ->OR->
       equalTo('artist', 'Tony')
 ->UNNEST;

 if($isDynamic){
    $select->where(array('test_id' => '1'));
 }

 $select->limit(1);

 return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
 }
```

You can use SQL like [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html)

Comment: That not what I am looking for, I know who to create a query using tableGateway